# show database : list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I practice how to use django to show data in my mongodb

When showing the `image` filed,there is error

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

the `image` filed save data like this :

```
{u'url': u'http://test/images/1.jpg', u'path': u'full/1.jpg', u'checksum': u'57b'}
```

And here is my views.py

```
def index(request):
shopping = Shopping.objects.all()
# html = shopping[1].date  # works well! output : 2014.08.23
aa = shopping[1].images   
html =  aa['url']
return HttpResponse(html)
```

my modes.py

```
class Shopping(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)      
    date        = models.CharField(max_length=100)      
    image_urls  = ListField()           #scrapy                 
    images      = ListField()           #scrapy
    objects     = MongoDBManager()
```

Please tell me how can I fix this?  Thank you!

Comment: what does images field look like? you have shown `image` it looks more like a pickle field than an image field

Comment: Looks like `aa = shopping[1].images` is a list of `image` dictionary you showed us in the question. In which case you would have to iterate over them.

Comment: image field is ListField()

Comment: It might be good in future, if possible, to include the traceback so we can see the actual line(s) of code that produced the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shopping[1].images is a ListField() meaning

```
 aa = shopping[1].images
```

will set aa to be a ListField() which you must access with an index to get to the image field you want.

try indexing aa with an integer first:

```
aa = shopping[1].images   
html =  aa[0]['url']
```